# Unable to use arraylist parameter in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I tried to pass the parameters to the constructor but i am stucked what to use for the arraylist in the method.
Constructor:

```
public Company(int companyid,String companyname, String companyowner, String startdate, String description,
             ArrayList<String> departments) {
    this.companyid=companyid;
    this.companyname = companyname;
    this.companyowner = companyowner;
    this.startdate = startdate;
    this.description = description;
    this.departments = departments;
}
```

Calling parameter in method:

```
Company company = new Company(obj.getInt("companyID"),obj.getString("comapnyName"),obj.getString("companyOwner"),obj.getString("companyStartDate"),obj.getString("companyDescription"),obj.getString("companyDepartments"));
company.setCompanyid(obj.getInt("companyID"));
company.setCompanyname(obj.getString("comapnyName"));
company.setCompanyowner(obj.getString("companyOwner"));
company.setStartdate(obj.getString("companyStartDate"));
company.setDescription(obj.getString("companyDescription"));


// Genre is json array
JSONArray companydept = obj.getJSONArray("companyDepartments");
ArrayList<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < companydept.length(); j++) {
    departments.add((String) companydept.get(j));
}
company.setDepartments(departments);
```

I am confused what to use in the method.Expected parameter is Arraylist but actual parameter used in the method is of String i don't know what to use over there.

Comment: You can use string builder or buffer to create comma separated string and then pass it to constructor. its easy.

Comment: Have you tried creating the ArrayList before instantiating the Company object, and pass that to the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) You can remove the `ArrayList<String> departments` parameter from the `Company` constructor and just have the `company.setDepartments(departments);` setter as you do now.

2) Create the `ArrayList<String> departments` first, then pass that to the constructor:

```
// Genre is json array
JSONArray companydept = obj.getJSONArray("companyDepartments");
ArrayList<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < companydept.length(); j++) {
     departments.add((String) companydept.get(j));
}

Company company = new Company(obj.getInt("companyID"),
                              obj.getString("comapnyName"),
                              obj.getString("companyOwner"),
                              obj.getString("companyStartDate"),
                              obj.getString("companyDescription"),
                              departments); // <--- Pass the ArrayList here
```

3) Have the Company constructor build the `ArrayList` by passing in the `JSONArray`.

```
public Company(int companyid,String companyname, 
               String companyowner, String startdate, 
               String description, JSONArray companydept) {
     this.companyid=companyid;
     this.companyname = companyname;
     this.companyowner = companyowner;
     this.startdate = startdate;
     this.description = description;

    // build it in the constructor here:
    this.departments = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < companydept.length(); j++) {
         departments.add((String) companydept.get(j));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

Move the following code before the constructor of Company (before you call new Company).

```
JSONArray companydept = obj.getJSONArray("companyDepartments");
ArrayList<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < companydept.length(); j++) {
    departments.add((String) companydept.get(j));
}
```

and call:

```
Company company = new Company(obj.getInt("companyID"),obj.getString("comapnyName"),obj.getString("companyOwner"),obj.getString("companyStartDate"),obj.getString("companyDescription"),obj.getString("companyDepartments"), departments);
```